# Scroll before ScrollView is loaded

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-scrollview

Hello, I have a question,

Is there any possibility to skip the first scroll's that occur before gridView is loaded?

To get only those when user really scrolls my list?

I am loading more, and that scroll before any user action is messing up.

Comment: you can use method setSelection()

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the gridView?
If you load it using addView you probably won't have problem.
In my opinion the best solution is to create a scrollView that contains a LinearLayout (for example vertical), then add at this LinearLayout a list of LinearLayouts (horizontal), and every layout contained in list contains yours elements.

Comment: Well I have that listView in a fragment that I load into frameLayout, every item inside my listView has its layout, however whenever my fragment is loading the "OnScroll" action is beign performed few times.